# Returning a char array of initially unknown length from a function in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I need to send json to a server. The code works perfect, but as I need to invoke it on two locations and as such want to make a function our of it. However, I cannot get it to work with a char array. A possibility is to convert the char array into a String I would expect, but that is not memory efficient I would expect. So I thought I would pass a pointer, allocate the size in the function and then return the length. But it doesn't seem to be working, the 'encoded' char* seems empty.

Is is probably something basic I do wrong.

This is the code:

```
      Serial.println("Connected");

      char* encoded;
      int contentLength = generateData(encoded);
      Serial.print("Data to be send, length: "); Serial.print(contentLength); Serial.println(" Data: "); Serial.println(encoded);
      // Send request to the server:
      client.println("POST /api/heartbeat HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host: localhost");
      client.println("Accept: */*");
      client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      client.print("Content-Length: ");
      client.println(contentLength + 5);
      client.println();
      client.print("data=");
      client.print(encoded);

      // Done here, as the response availability sometimes takes time.
      lastConnection = millis();
      updateServer = false;
      free(encoded);
```

And the function:

```
int generateData(char* encoded) {   
  Serial.println("Preparing the data to be send....");
  String inputString = "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"hostname\":\"";
  inputString += hostname;
  inputString += "\",\"build\":";
  inputString += build;
  inputString += ",\"hardware\":\"";
  inputString += hardware;
  inputString += "\",\"sensors\":[";

  bool firstSensor = true;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (temperatureValues[i] == 0) continue;
    if (!firstSensor) inputString += ",";
    inputString += "{\"sensor\":\"";
    inputString += temperatureAddresses[i];
    inputString += "\",\"value\":";
    inputString += String(temperatureValues[i]);
    inputString += ",\"type\":\"temp\"}";
    firstSensor = false;
  }

  inputString += "]";

  if (pendingResponses.length() > 0) {
    inputString += ",\"responses\":[";
    inputString += pendingResponses;
    inputString += "]";
    pendingResponses = "";
  }

  inputString += "}";

  byte plain[inputString.length() + 1];
  inputString.getBytes(plain, inputString.length() + 1);
  des.calc_size_n_pad(sizeof(plain));

  byte encodedByte[des.get_size()];
  byte plain_p[des.get_size()];
  des.padPlaintext(plain, plain_p);
  for (int i = 0; i < (des.get_size() / 8); i++) {
    byte intermitInput[8];
    byte intermitResult[8];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      intermitInput[j] = plain_p[(i * 8) + j];
    }
    des.encrypt(intermitResult, intermitInput, (byte*)key);
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      encodedByte[(i * 8) + j] = intermitResult[j];
    }
  }

  int inputLength = sizeof(encodedByte);
  int newLength = Base64.encodedLength(inputLength);
  encoded = (char*) malloc(newLength + 1);
  encoded[newLength] = '\0';

  // Base64 Encoder
  Base64.encode(encoded, (char*)encodedByte, inputLength);
  return newLength;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `encoded` by value

```
char* encoded;
int contentLength = generateData(encoded);
```

which means that when you assign it in `generateData()`

```
encoded = (char*) malloc(newLength + 1);
encoded[newLength] = '\0';
```

you're changing only a local variable.
The quickest fix would be to change `generateData()` to take its parameter by reference instead of value, and it should work

```
int generateData(char* &encoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack's idea should work.

But another idea would be to make a struct that contains a `char *` and an `int` (or `size_t`) and return that. Then you don't need to try to "return" anything through pointer or reference parameters.